# How do I generate offline transactions in Java?

Tags: development, thin-clients, bitcoinj, java

I'd like to develop a Java binding to the [Stratum Overlay Network](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=55842) (a server for thin clients). This requires [signing on offline transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=55842.msg667307#msg667307).

Can I directly use bitcoinj's API to do this? Can I copy-paste some java from from it?

In shorts, how would I generate/sign offline transactions in Java?

Comment: Taking a look at bccapi, it might help. http://code.google.com/p/bccapi/

Comment: See also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/how-do-i-create-an-offline-transaction-in-java-to-broadcast-via-blockchain-info

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the Overlay Network will be handling the transactions. It might follow the standard protocol, or develop its own. In any case, as the ON is still in proposal stage, everything can change still. Best advise is to follow the forum thread and the Google Doc and see where it settles at.

Comment: The article I linked to offer's slush's current explaination how to do this, I was hoping someone could help me elaborate that ... eventually helping me to get working code. Anyway, I know it's still a work in progress, I'm following it, and hopefully will have time to code something up in a few weeks.